# Django: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, url, deprecated

New python/Django user (and indeed new to SO):

When trying to migrate my Django project, I get an error:

```
RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated 
and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got main.views.home). Pass the callable instead.   
url(r'^$', 'main.views.home')
```

Apparently the second argument can't be a string anymore. I came to create this code as it is through a tutorial at pluralsight.com that is teaching how to use Django with a previous version (I'm currently working with 1.9). The teacher instructs us to create urlpatterns in urls.py from the views we create in apps. He teaches us to create a urlpattern such as the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', 'main.views.home')
]
```

to reference

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, "main/home.html",
                    {'message': 'You\'ve met with a terrible fate, haven\'t you?'}) #this message calls HTML, not shown, not important for question
```

in the views.py of an app "main" that I created.

If this method is being deprecated, how do I pass the view argument not as a string? If I just remove the quotes, as shown in the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/), I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'main' is not defined
```

I tried to "import" views or main using the code presented in this documentation:

```
from . import views
```

or

```
from . import main
```

which gave me:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'views'
```

and

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

I believe I've traced this down to an import error, and am currently researching that.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Django at one point changed the layout ever so slightly.  I _think_ you want from main import views, but am not certain... could you try that?

Comment: Yes, I've check that method as well and it works in the following way:

if using 'from main import views' then your url argument needs to be 'url(..., views.home)' , not 'url(..., main.views.home)'

@joey wilhelm illustrates that below

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. It was indeed an import error. For Django 1.10, you now have to import the app's view.py, and then pass the second argument of url() without quotes. Here is my code now in urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
import main.views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', main.views.home)
]
```

I did not change anything in the app or view.py files.

Props to @Rik Poggi for illustrating how to import in his answer to this question:
[Django - Import views from separate apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439447/django-import-views-from-separate-apps)

Comment: Full disclosure, I had found the answer to my question before posting it. I wanted to post it so that others wouldn't have to go on the same goose chase. This is my first time posting a question, and if that is not the best method to share information, please inform me to a better way.

Comment: Please mark your answer as the solution, if you have answered your own problem.

Comment: Thanks for the note, but I can't accept my own answer as a solution for 2 days after positing it, it seems.

Comment: Helped me, am following a tutorial trying to learn Django too

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from main import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home)
]
```

I'm not absolutely certain what your directory structure looks like, but using a relative import such as `from . import X` is for when the files are in the same folder as each other.

Comment: Yes! It seems that would work as well. I do prefer "import main.views" and then calling url(..., main.views.home) vs. "from main import views" and calling url(..., views.home) because I can keep the views accounted for once I have multiple apps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your functions by importing all of them to  list and added each one of them to urlpatterns.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from main.views import(
   home,
   function2,
   function3,
)

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^home/$', home),

   url(r'function2/^$', function2),
   url(r'^$', function3),
]
```

Comment: Are square braces `[]` now allowed with imports, you meant to use `()`?

Comment: Why do you add multiple views for exactly the same URL pattern? According to the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/ : "3. Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL, matching against path_info.". I'm not sure if that was already the case in the version having been current in 2016, but it stops at the first matching pattern for as long as I work with Django.

Comment: @MichaelS. you are right I have corrected.