# Following the django url instructions and it's not working

Tags: python, django

I get this error

```
Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be 
removed in Django 1.10 (got blog.views.landing). Pass the callable instead.
```

I try doing what the instructions in my apps urls.py which says

```
1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
```

but if I try

```
from blog import views
  urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.landing, name='landing'),
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I get an error, or if I use

```
import views or from . import views I still get an error
```

What am I not doing correctly? any and all help is appreciated

Comment: views.landing is CreateView, UpdateView or  DeleteView?

Comment: Neither. Just a landing page view. Does what I'm trying to do only work for the views you've mentioned? Because I don't see that specified anywhere.

Comment: Nope, you have to add "`.as_view()`" if you are using them.
Is not a URL problem is a view problem. Post the view and change the instructions you are flowing because deprecated in Django 1.1 it was a long time ago.

Comment: I'm using version 1.9

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096424/django-support-for-string-view-arguments-to-url-is-deprecated-and-will-be-rem

Comment: @ZartchI saw that before I posted this question. Thanks, though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98933/discussion-between-zartch-and-losee).

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @Sayse  they are the following     File "/Users/ray/Desktop/mypy/teletram/src/altura/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import views
ImportError: cannot import name 'views'

Comment: `.` in python 3.* refers to the current package it would appear as though you still need the `from blog.. ` as shown in your code snippet

Comment: Iv'e tried it that way as well

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the instructions you are following do not apply to the version of Django that you are using. What version of Django are you using? and How old are the instructions you are following? Django is a constantly changing beast and features that were in one version can be removed (deprecated) in later ones. I would recommend a review of the documentation on the the Djangoproject.org web site

Comment: I'm using version 1.9 django and the latest python