# Wrong code or wrong setup?

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to coding and I've been sitting for the last 5 hours trying to  make a website, but it gives me an error straight away. I've been looking all over for a solution but have not yet come by one.

This is the error code:

```
C:\Projects\bgcenv\myproject\urls.py:26: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for
string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10
(got myproject.views.index). Pass the callable instead.
  url(r'^$', 'myproject.views.index'),
```

This is my url.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
try:
    from django.conf.urls import url
except ImportError:  # django < 1.4
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import url


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', 'myproject.views.index'),
]
```

Comment: "Deprecated" typically means "We used to think this was OK, but now we know better, and we intend to disallow it entirely... one of these days, probably.".  It's so you have time to change your code before some future Django version refuses to run it at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096424/django-support-for-string-view-arguments-to-url-is-deprecated-and-will-be-rem)

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a warning, not an error, but what it's saying is that the url function (from django.conf.urls) is expecting you to pass a function (or another callable) instead of a string. You need to import index from myproject.views and pass that:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
try:
    from django.conf.urls import url
except ImportError:  # django < 1.4
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import url

from myproject import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #url(r'^$', 'myproject.views.index'),
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    # Importing the views module you can
    # now conveniently register other views:
    # url('r^/blah/', views.blah),
]
```