# Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Pass the callable instead

Tags: python, django

Here is my code which is giving warning.

It's giving warnings for strings like `"posts.views.post_list"` in `urlpatterns` and suggesting instead of strings pass the callable instead. I need to fix or remove that warning.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
#from django.contrib import admin

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', "posts.views.post_list"),
   url(r'^create/$', "posts.views.post_create"),
   url(r'^detail/$', "posts.views.post_detail"),
   url(r'^update/$', "posts.views.post_update"),
   url(r'^delete/$', "posts.views.post_delete"),    
   #url(r'^posts/$', "<app_name>.<views_py>.<function_name>"),
]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096424/django-support-for-string-view-arguments-to-url-is-deprecated-and-will-be-rem  duplicate ...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks you all guys I fixed that warning myself. Now its running fine without giving any warnings.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
#from django.contrib import admin

from .views import(
  post_list,
  post_create,
  post_detail,
  post_update,
  post_delete
)

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', post_list),
  url(r'^create/$', post_create),
  url(r'^detail/$', post_detail),
  url(r'^update/$', post_update),
  url(r'^delete/$', post_delete),    
  #url(r'^posts/$', "<app_name>.<views_py>.<function_name>"),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

As the warning says, passing strings to `url` is deprecated ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urls/#url)).

You have to pass the callable. This means import the function and pass it directly:

```
 urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.post_list),
   url(r'^create/$', views.post_create),
   url(r'^detail/$', views.post_detail),
   url(r'^update/$', views.post_update),
   url(r'^delete/$', views.post_delete),    
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the real function instead of a string consisting of the function's name:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
#from django.contrib import admin

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.post_list),
   url(r'^create/$', views.post_create),
   url(r'^detail/$', views.post_detail),
   url(r'^update/$', views.post_update),
   url(r'^delete/$', views.post_delete),    
   #url(r'^posts/$', <views_py>.<function_name>),
]
```